# Do concurrent web crawlers typically store visited URLs in a concurrent map, or use synchronization to avoid crawling the same pages twice?

Tags: java, python, multithreading, concurrency, web-crawler

I'm playing around writing a simple multi-threaded web crawler. I see a lot of sources talk about web crawlers as obviously parallel because you can start crawling from different URLs, but I never see them discuss how web crawlers handle URLs that they've already seen before. It seems that some sort of global map would be essential to avoid re-crawling the same pages over and over, but how would the critical section be structured? How fine grained can the locks be to maximize performance? I just want to see a good example that's not too dense and not too simplistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist to do it using only java concurrency framework, then the `ConcurrentHashMap` may be the way to go. The interesting method in it is the `ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent` method, it will give you very good efficiency, and the idea how to use it is:

You will have some "multithreaded source of incoming url addresses" from crawled pages - you can use some concurrent queue to store them, or just create a ExecutorService with (unbounded?) queue in which you will place Runnables that will crawl the urls.

Inside the crawling Runnables you should have a reference to this common ConcurrentHashMap of already crawled pages, and at the very begin of the `run` method do:

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long> crawledPages = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long>();
...

private class Crawler implements Runnable {
  private String urlToBeCrawled;

  public void Crawler(String urlToBeCrawled) {
    this.urlToBeCrawled = urlToBeCrawled;
  }

  public void run() {
    if (crawledPages.putIfAbsent(urlToBeCrawled, System.currentTimeMillis())==null) {
       doCrawlPage(urlToBeCrawled);
    }
  }
}
```

if `crawledPages.putIfAbsent(urlToBeCrawled)` will return null to you, then you know that this page was not crawled by anyone, since this method atomically puts the value you can progress with crawling this page - you're the lucky thread, if it will return a non-null value, then you know someone has already take care about this url, so your runnable should finish, and the thread goes back to pool to be used by next Runnable.

Answer (score 2):

**Specific domain use case : Use in memory**

If it is specific domain say abc.com then it is better to have vistedURL set or Concurrent hash map in memory, in memory will be faster to check visited status, memory consumption will be comparatively less. DB will have IO overhead and it is costly and visited status check will be very frequent. It will hit your performance drastically. As per your use case, you can use in memory or DB. My use case was specific to domain where visited URL will not be  again visited so I used Concurrent hash map.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ConcurrentHashMap` to store to find duplicate url.`ConcurrentHashMap` also use split lock mechanism instead of using global lock.

or you can use your own implementation where you can split your all data among different key.

For an example of Guava API

```
Striped<ReadWriteLock> rwLockStripes = Striped.readWriteLock(10);
String key = "taskA";
ReadWriteLock rwLock = rwLockStripes.get(key);
try{
     rwLock.lock();
     .....
}finally{
     rwLock.unLock();
}
```

ConcurrentHashMap example

```
 private Set<String> urls = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean>());
```

Answer (score 0):

**for crawler don't use ConcurrentHashMap, rather use Databse**

The number of visisted URL's will grow very fast, so it is not a good thing to store them in memory, better use a databese, store the URL and the date it was last crawled, then just check the URL if it already exists in DB or is eligible for refreshing. I use for example a Derby DB in embedded mode, and it works perfectly for my web crawler. I don't advise to use in memory DB like H2, because with the number of crawled pages you eventually will get OutOfMemoryException.

You will rather rarely have the case of crawling the same page more than once in the same time, so checking in DB if it was already crawled recently is enough to not waste significant resources on "re-crawling the same pages over and over". I belive this is "a good solution that's not too dense and not too simplistic"

Also, using Databse with the "last visit date" for url, you can stop and continue the work when you want, with ConcurrentHashMap you will loose all the results when app exit. You can use "last visit date" for url to determine if it needs recrawling or not.

Comment: Since you just want to insert in a set of visited urls and check for existence of a url in that set redis may be the best solution for this. You could also store a hash where the key will be the visited url and the value a last visit date. In any case almost any kind of database is better than an in-memory structure for this.

Comment: That's fine and all, but I still want to determine the minimum transactional guarantees required to avoid race conditions. I appreciate that a database is the way to go, but this project is primarily self-educational in nature, and I lose that if I just toss it in a database. Constraining the problem to using a data structure will allow me to see everything going on under the hood, namely, the critical section.